# concat multiple 2 dimensional arrays with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have multiple 2 dimensional arrays that I would like to concat into a single 2 dimensional array:

```
var data = [
  [["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["valu3"]],
  [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]],
  [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]
];
```

wanted result:

```
var result = [
  ["x", "data1", "data2"],
  ["value1", 0, 2],
  ["value2", 1, 1],
  ["value3", 2, 0]
];
```

So far I am try to zip and concat using apply but I can't have the result I want:

```js
var data = [
  [["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["valu3"]],
  [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]],
  [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]
];

var result = _.zipWith.apply(_, _.concat(data))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @Nina Scholz he did in the snippet behind the variable `result`

Comment: The wanted result is still a multi-dimensional array...

Comment: Adriani: sorry there was a typo in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lodash` transposing the matrix is as simple as this:

`_.zipWith(...data, _.concat)`

```js
var data = [
  [["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["valu3"]],
  [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]],
  [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]
]
var res = _.zipWith(...data, _.concat);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And also in Vanilla JS this is as simple as this

`data[0].map((_,i)=>data.map(r=>r[i][0]))`

```js
var data = [
  [["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["valu3"]],
  [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]],
  [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]
];

var res = data[0].map((_,i)=>data.map(r=>r[i][0]));

console.log(res);
```

**Note:** You don't even need the `_.concat` and only `_.zip` would work (without 2nd argument) if your each rows were not nested, in your data rows are not `[A, B, C, ...]`. your rows are `[[A], [B], [C], ...]` but in output you need simple array for rows, so the `_concat` is used to make them simple array for each resultant row. Similarly in plain JS version the `[0]` in `r[i][0]` is needed because we have a nested level data in each row, otherwise (for simple row as input) it could have been `r[i]`

Comment: Can you add a working snippet with the data in the question? Then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Here I have added working snippet in the answer with your data (provided in question). However, I haven't asked you to accept my answer, you should accept the best solution (whichever is) in order to help the community and users.

Answer (score 3):

What about using regular ES6 javascript ? :)

```js
const data = [
  [
    ['x'],
    ['value1'],
    ['value2'],
    ['valu3'],
  ],
  [
    ['data1'],
    [0],
    [1],
    [2],
  ],
  [
    ['data2'],
    [2],
    [1],
    [0],
  ],
];

const ret = data.map(x => x.reduce((tmp, y) => [
  ...tmp,
  ...y,
], []));

console.log(ret);
```

---

And in ES5 as asked for

```js
var data = [
  [
    ['x'],
    ['value1'],
    ['value2'],
    ['valu3'],
  ],
  [
    ['data1'],
    [0],
    [1],
    [2],
  ],
  [
    ['data2'],
    [2],
    [1],
    [0],
  ],
];

var result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
  var oneArray = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j += 1) {
    for (let k = 0; k < data[i][j].length; k += 1) {
      oneArray.push(data[i][j][k]);
    }
  }

  result.push(oneArray);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I've edited my post, hopes that's what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the ES5 answer. I still have to support IE11 in my organization... :/

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I feel so sorry for you right now :<. Good luck!

Comment: I feel ashame, this is not the result I was looking for. There was an error in my wanted result in the question...

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose the matrix.

```js
var data = [[["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["valu3"]], [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]], [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map(([v], i) => (r[i] || []).concat(v)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var data = [[["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["valu3"]], [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]], [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
          return a.map(function (v, i) {
              return (r[i] || []).concat(v);
          });
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Concise solution with the use of ES6 `destructuring` and lodash `_.zip`, `_.map` & `_.flatten`:

```js
var data = [[["x"], ["value1"], ["value2"], ["value3"]], [["data1"], [0], [1], [2]], [["data2"], [2], [1], [0]]]
    
var result = _.zip(..._.map(data, _.flatten))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called flatten. Lodash has 3 versions of that function.

```
const result = _.zip.apply(null, data).map(_.flatten)
```

Comment: sorry that's not the result I want

Comment: @BelowtheRadar exactly the same as wanted result https://repl.it/repls/KindheartedDetailedSpools

Comment: Look carefully at the wanted result in the question

Comment: @BelowtheRadar added zip

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution I was looking for!